# Adding\attaching gaols to media items programatically

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore-dms

For one of our requirements, we  need to attach goals to few types of media items.

Going though each item in media library and adding 'gaols' through 'Analyze' tab will be tedious as there are hundreds of items. Is there any way to do it through script or code?

For getting the goals\events attached, we can check in "_Tracking" field. But Im not getting the exact syntax to update this field.

Any hints?

Comment: What you ask is incomprehensible.
And SO is not a place where users provide scripts to others [mcve],
 [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this without coding or PowerShell, using the search functionality within Sitecore. First go to the Media Library, then find the specific folder you're interested in.

[image: Search icon]

With the folder selected you can then click on the little magnifying glass icon (next to the tabs Folder and Content). That will open a new tab where you can build a search query. 
After building that and getting your results back, you can click the little down arrow next to the search query, and click the 'Search Operations'. Select the 'Apply campaigns events', which will open an 'Attributes' pop-up.

[image: Search]

Go to the second tab called 'Events', and select your goals. 
[image: Attributes popup]

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need to attach a goal not a page event. Custom goals cant be seen here :(

Comment: While you're correct in that it shows only page events, to work around this is to go in the Marketing Control Panel, find your custom goal and untick the 'Is Goal' checkbox. Running through the tagging method as described above will now show your custom page event. After tagging your media items, you should now be able to go back into the Marketing Control Panel and check the 'Is Goal' checkbox again.